# Web crawling URLs and their URLs recursively

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

so I have been struggling with writing this web crawler for a few days and I don't know how to get it to work. I've been searching for similar questions and solutions, but I can't find anything, so please refer to another question if this has already been asked.

My web crawler is supposed to find *n* urls the first website is linked to, and then find *x* urls that these *n* urls are linked to and so forth until a certain depth is reached and with a certain amount of urls in each level. For example - I enter an URL I want to crawl, I find 3 linking URLs, 3 URLs linking to each of those 3 URLs and so forth. 1+3^1+3^2+3^4... urls. So far I've written this, but I can't get it to work as I want it to.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'http://www.baidu.com'
depth = 3 #3 levels
count = 3 #amount of urls in each level

def extractURL(url, depth, count):
  list = []
  response = requests.get(url)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
  tags = soup.find_all('a')
  newtags = tags[:depth]
  for link in newtags:
      url2 = link.get('href')
      if url2 is not None and url2.startswith("http"):
          list.append(url2)
  for url3 in list:
      if(count > 0):
          if not url3 is None and "http" in url:
             print(url, "->", url3)
             count = count-1
             print("----------------") #divider for each url and connecting urls..?
             extractURL(url3, depth, count)

extractURL(url, depth, count)
print("Done")
```

The point is for it to print "url ->(linking to) url2". I'm thinking my counter isn't working as it never resets, but I have no clue as to solve this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: try removing count from the function argument and then add `global count` at the first line of your function

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code to appropriately extract links.
You must separate each layer of links in order to eliminate duplicate link analysis

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'http://www.baidu.com'
depth = 3  # 3 levels
count = 3  # amount of urls in each level
url_list_depth = [[] for i in range(0, depth + 1)]
url_list_depth[0].append(url)
for depth_i in range(0, depth):
    for links in url_list_depth[depth_i]:
        response = requests.get(links)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        tags = soup.find_all('a')
        for link in tags:
            url_new = link.get('href')
            flag = False
            for item in url_list_depth:
                for l in item:
                    if url_new == l:
                        flag = True

            if url_new is not None and "http" in url_new and flag is False:
                url_list_depth[depth_i + 1].append(url_new)
                print(links, "->", url_new)

print('Done')
```